# jquery perform action with every element found with .find

Tags: jquery, html, find, nested, each

I have have the following HTML. (this is parsed by the system)
How do perform an action on each "find" element.
I like to perform an action with every found anchor

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="category">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li class="section">
        <h3>section title</h3>
        <ul class="article-list>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li class="section">
        <h3>section title</h3>
        <ul class="article-list>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="section">
        <h3>section title</h3>
        <ul class="article-list>
          <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$("ul li.category h2").each(function() {
    $category = $(this);    
    //do something with category;

    $($category).each(function() {
        console.log("category: " + $(this).text());

      $(this).find("ul.article-list li a").each(function() {
        //do something 
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: **What is the problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the only HTML on the page? Because

```
$("a").each(function() {
  // do something
});
```

would do just fine

If this is not the only code on the page, is this the only list on the page? In that case

```
$("ul li a").each(function() {
  // do something
});
```

would do just fine.

If anything more specific is needed, I'd suggest writing it like

```
$(".article-list > li > a").each(function() {
  // do something
});
```

You are trying to find childs of the H2 element, but the H2 doesn't have any childs. Your code would suggest that your HTML is marked up like this

```
<h2>
  <ul class="article-list">
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  </ul>
</h2>
```

EDIT: Also, your html is marked up faulty. `<ul class="article-list>` should be `<ul class="article-list">`

Comment: You are right. I was out of focus.
H2 doesn't have any child's. Thanks for the feedback.

I have updated my code. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's as per you current html elements.

```
$("ul li.category ul.article-list li a").each(function() {
    console.log("category: " + $(this).text());
    // do your action here
});
```

Comment: What would console logging the anchor achieve though? He wants to log the category name for clarity and do something else with the anchor

Comment: It's just for testing purpose, to check elements returned by selector. By ignoring log, he can perform the action within it.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML syntax is wrong you missed closing `"article-list"` class.Then there is no need of each in your case.You can select all the anchor tag like this `$('a')`.If you want to select all the anchor in `"article-list"` class then do like this `$(".article-list a")`

Working [demo](http://jsbin.com/cebibikifa/edit?html,js,console,output)